# Не работает (не запускается) pyrogram на сервере

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pyrogram

Столкнулся с проблемой зависания работы программы после метода run библиотеки pyrogram. С подобным встречаюсь впервые, ни ошибки, ни малейших подсказок о том, что ему надо.

Конфигурация:
ubuntu 18.04.6
Python3.10.13 установлен из исходников
После установки python сервер перезагружался
Библиотека pyrogram последней версии
TgCrypto тоже установлен
У python доступ к интернету есть (через requests запросы шлёт нормально)

На локальной машине запускается прекрасно, но на сервере нет. Помогите решить проблему кто с подобным сталкивался, а то у меня идеи кончились. Желательно без перезагрузки сервера, но если это необходимо, то напишите об этом.

Comment: Что значит «не работает» и «не запускается»? Что происходит вместо работы и запуска?

Comment: Просто зависает и всё. Метод run должен запрашивать данные для авторизации, но он этого не делает. Я знаю что у pyrogram исключения внутри либы обрабатываются, но если через pm2 запускать то логи этих исключений видны. По крайней мере в другом моём проекте это так. А тут вообще ничего! Просто зависает без исключений или других логов.

Comment: у меня такая же проблема. Подскажи как решил плиз)